# Drupal 7 Content type restrictions

Tags: drupal-7, content-type

How to add a restriction or validation for a content type that can be add only one content.

ex - Hotel web site room listing page should have only one content. After added once that only can edit or delete.

(I am a beginner for the Drupal)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Node Limit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit)? I have never used it, but seems suitable for what you want to get.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it is helpful, but i realized what i want is content type per taxonomy limitation, and that not developed in this module.